# Add icons in UITabItem for UITabBarViewController with Xcode 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uitabbaritem

I would to use a tabbar based app.

So, I added a UITabbarViewController in my storyboardapp but I can't configure the tab icons.
When I set the icon in the tabItem I see only a gray shape...

I use xcode 5.0.

Is there a particular way to set icons on the tabbar?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way: the images must be in white scale!

Answer (score 0):

You just set the icon for each view controller by pressing on the tab bar for that particular view controller and then changing the `image` property within Interface Builder.  Make sure you've added the images to Xcode first and then after you type the image name, hit enter and it should update it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I see what you can see in my screenshots.
You are using xcode 5? You have some particular types for picture about and/or size?

Comment: From Apple's docs: `If the image is too large to fit on the tab bar, it is clipped to fit.  The size of a tab bar image is typically 60 x 60 pixels.`

Comment: Yes, I used images 30x30 or 60x060 px

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the correctly sized images, otherwise it wouldn't be clipping it like it's shown in your image.

Comment: @Safari You should submit that as an answer so you can close out this question.